# html string to js script

Tags: javascript, html

i'm new to HTML and JavaScript but i have to change a string which represents a date in this format: DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS to this format: DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM. I am trying to get the value of {{msr.start}} inside of my javascript function so that i can use the slice() function to make it 3 characters shorter, can anyone please tell me how i can get the value of {{msr.start}} inside of my script? Thanks in advance :)

```
<td colspan="4" class="text-center text-middle" id="abc123">
  {{msr.start}} <--- this contains the right date and time
  <script>
    var tmp = {{msr.start}}.splice(0, 3) <--- here is where i want to use the date and time
    document.getElementById('abc123').innerHTML = tmp
  </script>
```

Comment: If `{{msr.start}}` outputs the plain date string, then you will have to put _quotes_ around this, to make it a text literal in JavaScript.

Comment: basicaly i can use the {{msr.start}}'s value in my html code but when i open the <script> i want to be able to access the value of {{msr.start}}

Comment: No need to repeat yourself, we already know that. Need to _pay attention_ though, because I already told you what you need to do. (Assuming this is a _server-side_ templating language you are using there, that information is currently missing from your explanation.)

Comment: I'm sorry I was having a hard time understanding but now that i saw how to do it I realized that you were right! Thank you very much for your time and effort I realy appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `let tmp = "{{msr.start}}"` and then use `substring()`
Example:

```js
let tmp = "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS" //You would use "{{msr.start}}"

console.log(tmp.substring(0, tmp.length - 3));
```

Comment: the problem is that {{msr.start}} is in my html code and i don't know how to get it inside of the <script>

Comment: What is the actual content of {{msr.start}} is it an entire html element?

Comment: no it's not a html element, it's the variable that contains the time and date, my code used to be like this: <td colspan="4" class="text-center text-middle">{{msr.start}}</td> and it would print the time and date but now i have to find a way to remove the seconds from {{msr.start}}

Comment: _“the problem is that {{msr.start}} is in my html code and i don't know how to get it inside of the <script>”_ - your script element is _also_ HTML, so it works the exact same way. All you need to do, is make the result into actually valid JS syntax.

Comment: thank you very much! it works perfectly now i had no idea you could just make it that simple :-). I have been stuck on such a small thing for over an hour now, greatly appreciate your help!!

Comment: @matthewfabrie, we've all been there.